# How to get the body(content) of javax.rs.ws.core.Response?

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs

May I know how to get the body(content) of `javax.rs.ws.core.Response`? I am implementing a get method to get a file from a server. I am setting the return type of my get method as `response.build()` where response is of type `ResponseBuilder`. On the client side I would like to know how to get the contents from this response object.

Comment: Show some code from the server and the client. What client framework or library are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`Response.getEntity()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#getEntity%28%29).

Comment: Isn't the question about how to get the response on the *client* side?

Comment: Indeed, that's what I was referring to. See here for an example: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs-client001.htm#BABBIHEJ

Comment: Wow... I didn't know there was a client api for JAX-RS. :)  I learned something new.

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the reasons why SO is so awesome. I learn most by answering other people's questions. _/_ didn't know about `Response.getEntity()` until I checked the API docs - now I know (until I forget ;-)).

Comment: If my response contains File (pdf) then How do I convert that data in pdf file object?

Answer (score 0):

What http client technology do you plan to use?  Java comes with a class called [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) that would allow you to make requests to your JAX-RS resource.  It has methods to allow you to fetch response headers (to get the response content-type for example) and a method to get an input stream so you can actually read the bytes sent by the server.

Alternatively you could use the Apache HttpComponents library which contains an [HTTPClient](https://hc.apache.org) that arguably has a nicer API than the built in Java HttpURLConnection class.